# Canonical Request \n Python 3

Tags: python

Ive been trying to figure this out all night with no luck.  Im assuming that this will be a simple question for the more experienced programmer. 
Im working on a canonical request that I can sign.
something like this:

```
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers
```

However when I print(canonical_request) I get:

```
method
canonical_uri
canonical_querystring
canonical_headers
```

But this is what im after:

```
method\ncanonical_uri\ncanonical_querystring\ncanonical_headers
```

By the way Im using python34,  I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to not have "actual" newlines, but the escape character for newlines in your string? Just add a second slash to `'\n'` to escape it as well, `'\\n'`. Or prepend your strings with r to make them "raw"; in them the backslash is interpreted literally; `r'\n'` (commonly used for regular expressions).

```
canonical_request = method + r'\n' + canonical_uri + r'\n' + canonical_querystring + r'\n' + canonical_headers
```

For information about string literals, see [String and byte literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative and more elegant way you can put your strings in a list and join them with escape the `\n` with add `\` to leading  :

```
>>> l=['method', 'canonical_uri', 'canonical_querystring', 'canonical_headers']
>>> print '\\n'.join(l)
method\ncanonical_uri\ncanonical_querystring\ncanonical_headers
```

> The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.